# como se puede hacer una doble consulta a una base de datos desde c#

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy comenzando con base de datos y tengo una consulta, ¿Que ocupo para hacer una consulta en una base de datos y preguntar si existe un cliente con el id del cliente que ingreso en el login de mi programa?. Pero debe existir en una tabla de mi base de datos y a su vez existir en otra tabla diferente.

En mi base de datos mi primera tabla se llama clientes, y mi segunda se llama afiliaciones, entonces yo ingreso clientes y en afiliaciones se muestran los clientes que se han afiliado, entonces como puedo hacer una consulta doble por así decirlo, ¿donde valido que en la tabla clientes existe ese cliente y en la tabla afiliación existe al menos una afiliación de ese cliente?.

mi consulta es así:

```
public string Login(string idCliente)
    {
string consulta="select idCliente From Cliente where idCliente = " + idCliente +
                "select idCliente From Afiliacion where idCliente = " + idCliente;
    
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conectar.conectar);       
    }
```

Me ayudarían explicándome una forma de hacer una doble consulta en dos tablas diferentes?

El problema es que deben cumplirse ambas cosas para dejar pasar al cliente, pero como son dos consultas aparte si el cliente existe en clientes pero no en afiliación igual lo deja, pero ocupo validar las dos cosas que existe en clientes y en afiliación.

¿Se pueden usar consultas concatenandolas con && ?

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer con una sola consulta. Prueba algo como `"SELECT c.idCliente FROM Cliente  c INNER JOIN Afiliacion a ON c.idCliente=a.idCliente WHERE c.idCliente=" + idCliente`

Comment: Ese código está abierto a inyección de SQL. Aprende a evitarlo usando consultas parametrizadas. mediante el metodo `Parameters.Add()`.

Comment: Los comentarios te llevan por el camino correcto, pero algo de lo que explicas aca no me cierra.. No deberias hacer esto en ningun caso.. porque en alguna de las dos tablas seguro existe porque una tabla es la PK de la otra no? entonces alcanzaria con buscar en la segunda, ya que en la primera deberia existir si o si... Ademas, suena raro que valides de esta forma....

Comment: @gbianchi eso es una buena opservacion jejeje , y si ahora que lo analizo igualmente  creo que alcanzaria con ocnsultar en la segunda

Comment: igualmente muchas gracias @Jaime Menéndez  ee gracias por eso ee porque igualmente ocupo aprender como hacer consultas anidadas , nose si se les diga asi , pero gracias por eso

Comment: Sinceramente no entendi eso @Luis Cazares

Comment: Esto que te estan mostrando, no son consultas anidadas... aca estas uniendo dos tablas....

Comment: @gbianchi me imagino que usar el join para unir dos elementos de dos tablas diferentes seria una forma diferente verdad ?

Comment: porque al final anidar dos consultas o hacer un join para unir los elementos de dos tablas diferentes seria tecnicamente lo mismo que quiero hacer pero de formas diferentes, estoy en lo sierto ?

Comment: una forma diferente de que? anidar consultas es hacer un select de select.. aca no estas haciendo eso en ningun lado...